# Pipe `|` character in formulas (functions)

Tags: pipe, formula, openoffice-calc

I ran across the following in an example describing RANK function in Apache OpenOffice Calc:

```
=RANK(5; {3;5|2.6;1}; 1)
```

I cannot figure out what the pipe character does. I have been playing around with it a little bit and still scratching my head:

[image: examples including pipe character]

Can anyone shed some light?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pipe character separates the rows of an array.  All rows must have the same number of elements, or else an error occurs.  So this causes an error because there is only a single element in the second row:

```
=AVERAGE(({3;5|2.6|8;1})
```

But this does not cause an error, because there are two elements in each row.

```
=AVERAGE(({3;5|2.6;1|8;1})
```

When using functions such as AVERAGE and RANK, using one- or multiple-dimensional arrays has the same effect, which is why replacing `|` with `;` does not change the result, as long as the arrays are of legal size.

Documentation is at https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Using_Arrays#Introduction.